# iCalendar (RFC5545) recurrence rule multiple times a day

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445, rrule, rfc5545

How can I make an event occur multiple times a day using the RRULE specified in RFC5545?

Lets say I would like an event to happen every other week on Monday and Friday at 11AM and 18PM. Is it possible to format the RRULE like something as the following:

> RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=MO,FR;[TIMES=110000,180000]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use the byhour
The BYHOUR rule part specifies a COMMA-
      separated list of hours of the day.  Valid values are 0 to 23.

so that would be :

RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=MO,FR;BYHOUR=11,18

Comment: Thanks, but what if the event has to occur at 11:25AM and 18:56PM?

Comment: then you need to have combination of byhour, byminute and bysetpos: RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=MO,FR;BYHOUR=11,18;BYMINUTE:25,56;BYSETPOS:1,4,5,8

Comment: I see, I was a bit confused by the BYSETPOS part. Is it necessary to write BYSETPOS:1,4,5,8 or can I omit 5,8 to just have BYSETPOST:1,4? (1: 11:25 yes, 2: 11:56 no, 3: 18:25 no, 4: 18:56 yes)

Comment: with 1,4 you only get your meetings on monday 11:25 and 18:56 but not on friday